# Binary file size bigger than expected c++

Tags: c++, file

this code creates file with size of 2338 bytes

```
ofstream ofs("out", ios::binary);
ofs << htonl(1);
int size = sizeof(htonl(1));
for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++){
    ofs << htons((unsigned short)(sin(i/5)*1000));
    size += sizeof(htons((unsigned short)(sin(i/5)*1000)));
}
cout << "file size : " << size << endl;
ofs.close();
```

but output is "file size : 1004" why file size isn't actually 1004 bytes?

Comment: Look up what `sizeof` does. Hint: It does not give you the number of bytes when printed.

Comment: `i/5` is integer division intended here?

Comment: @Borgleader I already fixed this, but thanks for observation

Comment: @nwp I thought that in binary mode it will print bytes, not the character representation of numbers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you open the file in a text editor, you'll quickly see what's wrong.

The numbers are being printed in their decimal representation, and not written as their internal (binary) representation.

Instead, use [`ostream::write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) :

```
uint32_t foo = htonl(1);
ofs.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&foo), sizeof(foo));
```

Answer (score 2):

> but output is "file size : 1004" why file size isn't actually 1004 bytes?

Because `std::ostream::operator<<()` output number in text format, so for example number 1 takes 1 byte, number 1000 takes 4 etc. `sizeof()` gives you size of data type in bytes. Those are unrelated numbers and you cannot expect them to match.

If you want to write binary data, use `std::ostream::write()` - then your numbers would match (but you cannot read that file by a text editor).